# Who has written Mahabharat epic?

Tags: mahabharata

From many posts here it is known that Ramayan was written by sage Valmiki. But i dont know who has written Mahabharat?

So who has written Mahabharata?

Comment: Veda Vyasa Krishna Dwaipayana has written Mahabharata and all puranas (at least major ones).

Comment: Do you know about VedaVyasa?

Comment: I have no idea sir.

Comment: I am learning slowly from this site. I have zero knowledge in Puran etc. But I am interested to know and learn these.

Comment: @K.C.Polai This is a Q&A site, it's not meant to be a replacement for Google search/Wikipedia. Please see this [meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/224).

Comment: @sv. Google may give you results but if no proof but here for each answer there is a cite source as a proof. So I believe this site much. If it is really wrong i am doing here then please tell me.. I will never come to this site.

Comment: Don't think of leaving site but minimum research effort is required before posting a question. Very simple questions which can be answered through Google search  are not considered good questions. Don't take google with a grain of salt. Every member here also searches google and the internet for searching answers.  So, google for very basic queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [Adi parva, Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm)

**Narrator (रचयिता)**:

> Krishna Dvyapana (who holds the title of Vedvyasa in 28th Dwapar yuga)

**Scribe (लेखक):**

> Lord Ganesha

This question is related to below questions:

[What script did Ganesha write the Mahabharata in?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/what-script-did-ganesha-write-the-mahabharata-in)

[How do we know that Lord Ganesha wrote the Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/how-do-we-know-that-lord-ganesha-wrote-the-mahabharata)

Comment: You may mention the source as Mahabharata from links [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/how-do-we-know-that-lord-ganesha-wrote-the-mahabharata/20760#20760)

Comment: @Tezz Agreed, didn't check that. Then question should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: But still edit your answer and add links. It's better if you use authentic links/scriptures in answer. @YDS at least you can just mention as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm) of Mahabharata...